# DAX SUM outside current context

Tags: sql, dax

This is my current data model ->
[part of data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVkXA.png)

I need help in creating a measure.

The measure I want to create should show the overall capacity of the ships that had trips in a time interval, as well as be able to see the total capacity based on the room type.

I am interested in obtaining the DAX equivalent of :

```
SELECT SUM(sc.capacity)
FROM Reporting.Trips t
    JOIN Reporting.Dates d ON d.DateId = t.DateId
    JOIN Reporting.ShipCapacities sc on sc.ShipId = t.ShipId
WHERE d.FiscalYear= 2017 AND d.FiscalWeek=15
```

OR per type

```
SELECT SUM(sc.capacity)
FROM Reporting.Trips t
    JOIN Reporting.Dates d ON d.DateId = t.DateId
    JOIN Reporting.ShipCapacities sc on sc.ShipId = t.ShipId
WHERE d.FiscalYear= 2017 AND d.FiscalWeek=15 and sc.CabinTypeId = 11
```

I tried to define a measure in this manner:

```
Total Rooms:=CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Ship Capacities'[Ship Capacity] ) )
```

I have seen that this outputs the T-SQL equivalent of:

```
SELECT SUM(Capacity)
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT sc.*
FROM Reporting.Trips t
    JOIN Reporting.Dates d ON d.DateId = t.DateId
    JOIN Reporting.ShipCapacities sc on sc.ShipId = t.ShipId
WHERE d.FiscalYear= 2017 AND d.FiscalWeek=15
) x
```

OR per type

```
SELECT SUM(Capacity)
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT sc.*
FROM Reporting.Trips t
    JOIN Reporting.Dates d ON d.DateId = t.DateId
    JOIN Reporting.ShipCapacities sc on sc.ShipId = t.ShipId
WHERE d.FiscalYear= 2017 AND d.FiscalWeek=15 and sc.CabinTypeId = 11
) x
```

These are the query results ->[Query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogk3v.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is the result from the measure you tried? It seems it doen't filter the Year and FiscalWeek unless you are using explicit filters. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, I compared the values. I am using explicit filters. I have a Parameters sheet where I have a table, included in the model. This filters measures in this way: Dates[Fiscal Year]=VALUES(Parameters[Current Fiscal Year]), Dates[Fiscal Week]=VALUES(Parameters[Current Fiscal Week]).

Comment: I guess it is an issue for DAX in a cases of many to many relations. From Trips to Ships there is a many to one relation. From Ships to Ship Capacities there is a 1 to many relation. I am looking for a way to use calculate like I want it, not like DAX currently does.

Comment: What is your expected result? Could you add sample data?

Comment: I added a print screen with the result of the queries ( at the end of the post).

Answer (score 0):

This is the final measure that worked for me:

```
Total Rooms:=CALCULATE (
    SUMX (
        'Ship Capacities',
        'Ship Capacities'[Ship Capacity]
            * COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( Trips, AND( Trips[Sailed] = TRUE (),Trips[ShipId] = 'Ship Capacities'[ShipId] ) ))
    )
)
```

Notice the COUNTROWS.
In the case of a many to one, then a one to many relation, it did not iterate (but previously I used SUM and not SUMX). 
I found it unusual that I have to mention the relation between the many to many tables. 
Otherwise it does not work.